# VirtualProtectEx called from service returns false but GetLastError is 0 (success)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, windows-services

Why [`VirtualProtectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa366899(v=vs.85).aspx) function fails when called from a service application? already is executed from a simply application all works fine.

Then, there is a possibility to make this function works also from a service?

Here is my code:

```
void WriteProcMem(HANDLE hProcess, VOID *pAddr)
{
    DWORD oldProtection;
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
    BYTE data[] = { 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90 }; // Only a example of assembly data

    if (!VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)pAddr, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection)) {
        printf("\n VirtualProtectEx() error - %d\n", GetLastError());

        //=============== To debug from service application ===================

        FILE * pFile;
        pFile = fopen("C:\\myfile.txt", "w");
        if (pFile != NULL)
        {

            char * str = new char[100];
            sprintf(str, "%d", GetLastError());

            fputs(str, pFile);
            fclose(pFile);
        }

        //======================================================================

        return;
    }

    if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)pAddr, &data, sizeof(data), &bytesWritten)) {

        printf("\n Data written success! \n");

        if (!VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)pAddr, sizeof(DWORD), oldProtection, &oldProtection))
            printf("\n VirtualProtectEx() [2] error - %d \n", GetLastError());
    }

}
```

> *The service executes a child process in debug mode and with SYSTEM account, these data should be written on "**child.exe**".*

---

***EDITION:***

After answer of @S.M. the real value returned by `GetLastError()` is:

> **ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE**: 6 (0x6) - The handle is invalid.

But like i already said, when not is executed as a service, all works fine. Why this is happening?

Comment: "*the real value returned by `GetLastError()` is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`*" - then obviously the `hProcess` you pass to `VirtualProtectEx()` is not valid. Where does that handle come from exactly? You did not show the code that is calling `WriteProcMem()`

Comment: Why are you even calling VirtualProtectEx? You can call WriteProcessMemory directly and let it take care of protection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, sorry by not showed this part: *`"You did not show the code that is calling WriteProcMem()"`*. But you suggestion was a advice to back on this part and see that exists a `CloseHandle(pi.hProcess;)` before `WriteProcMem(pi.hProcess, MemAddr);`. Thank you.

Comment: *exists a `CloseHandle(pi.hProcess)` before `WriteProcMem(pi.hProcess, MemAddr);`* of course this explain `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, but you also say *when not is executed as a service, all works fine* - this can not be, if executed the same fragment of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer on your title.

The line `pFile = fopen("C:\\myfile.txt", "w");` calls Windows API functions and probably resets the last error code. So the proper dealing with the last error code is saving it into a variable right after interesting API call. Try the code below and you should get the real error code after VirtualProtectEx call.

```
if (!VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)pAddr, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection)) {
    int err_code = GetLastError();
    printf("\n VirtualProtectEx() error - %d\n", err_code):

    //=============== To debug from service application ===================

    FILE * pFile = fopen("C:\\myfile.txt", "w");
    if (pFile != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(pFile, "%d\n", err_code);
        fclose(pFile);
    }
    ...
```